# how can I add an roxygen @export all functions in a package

Tags: regex, r, roxygen2

I am taking over an existing package. The package was written with .Rd documentation before R required functions to be explicitly exported.

My first step was to convert the documentation to roxygen using [Rd2roxygen](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rd2roxygen/) (many many thanks to Yihui and Hadley for this package!).

But now the package does not work because the functions are not exported. I would rather just export all functions by default. At this point it seems that my general approach would be to identify a regexp that can be found for each function ( `##' @return` would be a good target) and insert  `##' @export` in the line above it,

In pseudocode:

```
for all files in the `R/` directory{
   for each line starting in `##' @return`{ 
      insert `##' @export` in the preceeding line
}}
```

The result would be to replace:

```
##' @return something
```

with

```
##' @export
##' @return something that varies with each function
```

Getting a list of functions and adding them to NAMESPACE will not work because `devtools::document("mypackage")` will overwrite it if `@export` is not in the roxygen code above each function.

**Question:** what would be the most efficient way to add @export to the roxygen documentation for each function in the package?

An even better alternative would be to parse the `NAMESPACE` and parse `export` and `method` statements accordingly.

Comment: The docs are pretty clear that it's not supported in `Rd2roxygen` and that patches are welcome.  (See `package?Rd2roxygen`)  So, if you get a good answer, you should consider submitting it as a patch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Using only the functions exported in `NAMESPACE`, and assuming they do not have an `@export` statement somewhere in their Roxygen block, we can do a hacky parse of all the `export`ed functions:

```
NAMESPACE <- readLines("NAMESPACE")
exported_fns <- grep( "^export\\(", NAMESPACE, value=TRUE )
exported_fn_names <- gsub( "export\\((.*)\\)", "\\1", exported_fns )
fn_match_re <- paste("^", exported_fn_names, " ?<- ?", sep="")

for( file in list.files("./R", full.names=TRUE) ) {
  doc <- readLines( file )
  for( i in seq_along(doc) ) {
    if( any( sapply( fn_match_re, function(x) {
      length( grep( x, doc[i] ) ) > 0
      } ) ) ) {
      doc[i] <- paste( "##' @export", doc[i], sep="\n" )
    }
  }
  writeLines( doc, file )
}
```

Comment: hm. that is a good start, with two immediately apparent bugs: 1) it writes multiple `##' @export\n##' @return` per function and 2) the contents of `@return` are lost

Comment: Ah - if you want to make sure you're only matching `@return`, you could try `gsub( "^##' @return (.*)", "##' @export\n##' @return \\1", doc )`. This assumes all `@return` statements are followed by a space and some return string. I wasn't sure if you wanted to modify the `@return` statement in some way.

Comment: It would be great if one of you can send me a pull request on Github. The patch you have got is good enough in my eyes. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! I submitted a pull request with everything wrapped up as a function.

Comment: Just FYI, `@export` is supported in Rd2roxygen 1.2 now.